# Issue with confirm dialog box on IE9

Tags: javascript, confirm

Am using a confirm box as follows

```
if(! confirm("Are you sure?")){
                    return false;
                }else{
//Some code to execute
}
```

After am press 'Cancel' button on dialog box 10- 11 time the box is not appearing on IE9.
Any body have felt this issue before?? Please give some ideas to fix it

Comment: Don't show the dialog box 10 times...?

Comment: 10-11 times in what kind of timeframe?

Answer (score -1):

I would structure is a little differently so code doesn't hang around in memory. Setting it as a var will ensure it gets overwritten if you click it again.

```
var response = confirm('Are you sure?');
if(response){ return false; }

// Do something here.
```

You don't technically need the else{}, as return false will terminate the current function.

Comment: The code the OP shows does nothing to keep anything in memory. Your code, on the other hand, very well may (if there are any closures defined in the context, which there almost certainly will be if it's global). None of which has anything to do with the OP's stated problem in any case.

Comment: The var will get picked up by GC almost immediately since it's not being used anywhere further down the code.

Comment: @ ultraviol3tlux: Read the comment again, I think you missed two important parts. :-) (And yes, on an optimizing engine -- not all are -- the engine can optimize the content of the execution context's binding object. But again, A) The OP's code didn't even require the optimizer to do that, by not saving it *at all*. and B) This has nothing whatsoever to do with the OP's question.)